# CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

Tags: php

I looked up google for more information. But the more I read, the more I am confused or wonder

I understand that `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION()` follows "the location", but what is the location? Is it the url that is initialized?

```
  curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
```

I only need to post data into icontact mailing list - so would this snippet above prevent the data from going in the mailing list?

I printed `$result` and see that the data went in the correct mailing list although I cannot see whether the data are the correct ones which are from form.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Quoting from [docs](http://es.php.net/curl_setopt):

> **CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION**    `TRUE` to follow any "Location: " header that the
>   server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP
>   will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless
>   `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` is set).

When you request a URL, you can sometimes be redirected to some other URL. In PHP it'd be done with:

```
header('Location: http://example.com/');
```

This directive instructs CURL to load that URL instead of the original one, as HTTP mandates. There's normally no good reason to disable it.

Comment: but if I enable it, it makes no difference if only data is posted into icontact list? and I do not want any redirect?

Comment: It doesn't affect the request, if affects the response. It tells CURL what to do after the response is received.

Comment: "There's normally no good reason to disable it". If you are developing a webpage, you should not disable it. But if you are developing a RIA, maybe, you don't want to be redirected anywhere, because it'd be weird for the users.

Comment: @Tomás - I can't figure out what the reference to RIA has to do with the question or with curl. PHP is a server-side language. The user has no way to know how you fetch the data you send. The browser only talks with you, not with whatever third-party server you connect to from the server. But if you disobey the data provider instructions you'll possibly end up with no data to send.

Comment: Oh. Then I got confused. I thought the redirection would redirect the user too, but as you say, it only redirects curl. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It tells CURL to ignore 30x HTTP redirect headers or not. If set to true, `"Location: <someurl>"` HTTP headers in the response will cause CURL to issue another request to the location specified in this header.

Comment: so if I set it to false, the data will still be posted into icontact mailing list and not be affected, correct?

Comment: As far as I understand what you want, I think that it will have no effect over that.

Comment: thanks very much and i hope data is still posted into icontact list but I couldn't see the actual list. Thanks again for explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to true (or 1), cURL will automatically follow these redirects. This means that if the server responds with a 3xx status code (e.g., 302 Found, 301 Moved Permanently, etc.), cURL will make a new request to the URL specified in the Location header of the response.

If you set CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to false (or 0), cURL will not follow redirects. In this case, you'll receive the response for the redirect response (3xx status) rather than the final destination.